# How to do sequence of operations and ensure one operation is complete before next one in Spring Reactor web app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have Spring Boot 2 web app in which I need to identify site visitor by cookie and gather page view stats. So I need to intercept every web request.  The code I had to write is more complex than call back hell (the very problem Spring reactor was supposed to solve).

Here is the code:

```
package mypack.conf;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableReactiveMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.http.HttpCookie;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseCookie;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;

import mypack.dao.PageViewRepository;
import mypack.dao.UserRepository;
import mypack.domain.PageView;
import mypack.domain.User;
import mypack.security.JwtProvider;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
@Configuration


@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypack")
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = "mypack")
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private PageViewRepository pageViewRepository;


    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;


    @Bean
    public WebFilter sampleWebFilter()  {
        return new WebFilter() {

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

                String uri = exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString();
                String path = exchange.getRequest().getPath().pathWithinApplication().value();


                HttpCookie  cookie = null;
                String token = "";
                Map<String, List<HttpCookie>> cookies = exchange.getRequest().getCookies();


                try {
                    if((exchange.getRequest().getCookies().containsKey("_token") )
                            &&  (exchange.getRequest().getCookies().getFirst("_token"))!=null  ) {

                        cookie = exchange.getRequest().getCookies().getFirst("_token");
                        token = cookie.getValue();


                        return userRepository.findByToken(token).map(user -> {

                                exchange.getAttributes().put("_token", user.getToken());


                                PageView pg = PageView.builder().createdDate(LocalDateTime.now()).URL(uri).build();
                                pageViewRepository.save(pg).subscribe(pg1 -> {user.getPageviews().add(pg1); });

                                userRepository.save(user).subscribe();
                                    return user;
                            })


                            .flatMap(user-> chain.filter(exchange)); // ultimately this step executes regardless user exist or not

                    // handle case when brand new user first time visits website    
                    } else {
                        token = jwtProvider.genToken("guest", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        User user = User.builder().createdDate(LocalDateTime.now()).token(token).emailId("guest").build();
                        userRepository.save(user).subscribe();
                        exchange.getResponse().getCookies().remove("_token");

                        ResponseCookie rcookie  = ResponseCookie.from("_token", token).httpOnly(true).build();
                        exchange.getResponse().addCookie(rcookie);
                        exchange.getAttributes().put("_token", token);

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                return chain.filter(exchange);
            } // end of  Mono<Void> filter method
        }; // end of New WebFilter (anonymous class)
    }

}
```

Other relevant classes:

```
@Repository
public interface PageViewRepository extends   ReactiveMongoRepository<PageView, String>{

    Mono<PageView> findById(String id);

}


@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends   ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String>{

    Mono<User> findByToken(String token);

}





@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String token;


    @Default
    private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();

    @DBRef
    private List<PageView> pageviews;

}



Data
@Document
@Builder
public class PageView {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String URL;

    @Default
    private LocalDateTime createdDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

Relevant part of gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {

        springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')

    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client')
    compile('org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.3.4.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile "org.springframework.security:spring-security-jwt:1.0.9.RELEASE"
    compile "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0"

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    testCompile('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')

    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind')
}
```

The problem is in these lines:

> PageView pg =
>   PageView.builder().createdDate(LocalDateTime.now()).URL(uri).build();
>                                 pageViewRepository.save(pg).subscribe(pg1 -> {user.getPageviews().add(pg1); });

which hangs the browser (keeps waiting for response).

Basically what I want is this:
Must not use block() which does not even work in webfilter code as block also
hangs the browser.
Save pageview in mongo db. After it is saved, pageview has valid mongodb id which is needed to be stored as reference in pageviews List of user entity. Therefore only after it is saved in db, the next step is update user's pageviews List.
Next step is save the updated user without effecting downstream controller methods which may also update user and may need to save the user too.
All this should work in the given WebFilter context.

How to solve this problem?

The solution provided must make sure that user is saved in webfilter before passing on to controller actions some of which also saves user with different values from query string params.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly and you just need to run those long database operations in parallel so as not to block the filter and, in fact, the request itself?

Comment: Hello @ace, did the 2 existing posts answer your question? Otherwise I'll work on your issue from tomorrow ;)

Comment: Bsquare solutions provided does not solve my problem, see my comments on Cepr0 answer.

Comment: @ace what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 14):

If I understand you correctly, you need to perform long operations with database asynchronously to prevent the filter (and the request itself) from blocking?

In this case, I would recommend the following solution that works for me:

```
@Bean
public WebFilter filter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest req = exchange.getRequest();
        String uri = req.getURI().toString();
        log.info("[i] Got request: {}", uri);

        var headers = req.getHeaders();
        List<String> tokenList = headers.get("token");

        if (tokenList != null && tokenList.get(0) != null) {
            String token = tokenList.get(0);
            log.info("[i] Find a user by token {}", token);
            return userRepo.findByToken(token)
                    .map(user -> process(exchange, uri, token, user))
                    .then(chain.filter(exchange));
        } else {
            String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            log.info("[i] Create a new user with token {}", token);
            return userRepo.save(new User(token))
                    .map(user -> process(exchange, uri, token, user))
                    .then(chain.filter(exchange));
        }
    };
}
```

Here I slightly change your logic and take the token value from the appropriate header (not from cookies) to simplify my implementation.

So if the token is present then we try to find its user. If the token isn't present then we create a new user. If the user is found or created successfully, then the `process` method is calling. After that, regardless of the result, we return `chain.filter(exchange)`.

The method `process` puts a token value to the appropriate attribute of the request and call asynchronously the method `updateUserStat` of the `userService`:

```
private User process(ServerWebExchange exchange, String uri, String token, User user) {
    exchange.getAttributes().put("_token", token);
    userService.updateUserStat(uri, user); // async call
    return user;
}
```

User service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;
    private final PageViewRepo pageViewRepo;

    public UserService(UserRepo userRepo, PageViewRepo pageViewRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
        this.pageViewRepo = pageViewRepo;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Async
    public void updateUserStat(String uri, User user) {
        log.info("[i] Start updating...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        pageViewRepo.save(new PageView(uri))
                .flatMap(user::addPageView)
                .blockOptional()
                .ifPresent(u -> userRepo.save(u).block());
        log.info("[i] User updated.");
    }
}
```

I've added here a small delay for test purposes to make sure that requests work without any delay, regardless of the duration of this method.

A case when the user is found by the token:

```
2019-01-06 18:25:15.442  INFO 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Got request: http://localhost:8080/users?test=1000
2019-01-06 18:25:15.443  INFO 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Find a user by token 84b0f7ec-670c-4c04-8a7c-b692752d7cfa
2019-01-06 18:25:15.444 DEBUG 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : Created query Query: { "token" : "84b0f7ec-670c-4c04-8a7c-b692752d7cfa" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
2019-01-06 18:25:15.445 DEBUG 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : find using query: { "token" : "84b0f7ec-670c-4c04-8a7c-b692752d7cfa" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
2019-01-06 18:25:15.457  INFO 4992 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Get all users...
2019-01-06 18:25:15.457  INFO 4992 --- [         task-3] : [i] Start updating...
2019-01-06 18:25:15.458 DEBUG 4992 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
2019-01-06 18:25:16.459 DEBUG 4992 --- [         task-3] : Inserting Document containing fields: [URL, createdDate, _class] in collection: pageView
2019-01-06 18:25:16.476 DEBUG 4992 --- [         task-3] : Saving Document containing fields: [_id, token, pageViews, _class]
2019-01-06 18:25:16.479  INFO 4992 --- [         task-3] : [i] User updated.
```

Here we can see that updating the user is performed in the independent `task-3` thread after the user already has a result of 'get all users' request.

A case when the token is not present and the user is created:

```
2019-01-06 18:33:54.764  INFO 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Got request: http://localhost:8080/users?test=763
2019-01-06 18:33:54.764  INFO 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Create a new user with token d9bd40ea-b869-49c2-940e-83f1bf79e922
2019-01-06 18:33:54.765 DEBUG 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : Inserting Document containing fields: [token, _class] in collection: user
2019-01-06 18:33:54.776  INFO 4992 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Get all users...
2019-01-06 18:33:54.777  INFO 4992 --- [         task-4] : [i] Start updating...
2019-01-06 18:33:54.777 DEBUG 4992 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
2019-01-06 18:33:55.778 DEBUG 4992 --- [         task-4] : Inserting Document containing fields: [URL, createdDate, _class] in collection: pageView
2019-01-06 18:33:55.792 DEBUG 4992 --- [         task-4] : Saving Document containing fields: [_id, token, pageViews, _class]
2019-01-06 18:33:55.795  INFO 4992 --- [         task-4] : [i] User updated.
```

A case when the token is present but user is not found:

```
2019-01-06 18:35:40.970  INFO 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Got request: http://localhost:8080/users?test=150
2019-01-06 18:35:40.970  INFO 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Find a user by token 184b0f7ec-670c-4c04-8a7c-b692752d7cfa
2019-01-06 18:35:40.972 DEBUG 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : Created query Query: { "token" : "184b0f7ec-670c-4c04-8a7c-b692752d7cfa" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
2019-01-06 18:35:40.972 DEBUG 4992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] : find using query: { "token" : "184b0f7ec-670c-4c04-8a7c-b692752d7cfa" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
2019-01-06 18:35:40.977  INFO 4992 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Get all users...
2019-01-06 18:35:40.978 DEBUG 4992 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
```

My demo project: [sb-reactive-filter-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-reactive-filter-demo)

Comment: Cepr0 updateUserStat in userService uses block(). will this change to blocking and thus defeat the purpose of using reactive API ?  My question says Must not use block().  I maybe missing something, can u elaborate on this?

Comment: @ace The code of `updateUserStat` doesn't block the execution of the filter and controller methods at all. It runs in an independent thread and 'blocks' just its own execution to make the reactive repository saves data. You can run my demo and check it. You can increase the delay in `updateUserStat` and see that it doesn't affect to any requests.

Comment: @ace The trick is that the method `process` does not wait for the `updateUserStat` to finish and immediately returns control to the main process.

Comment: Cepr0  I used your approach in my project after a lot of recoding, unfortunately it does not work. It only work for the root path which does shows static page and user is updated but when I go to other pages that shows list of items from mongodb for example, it hangs browser keeps waiting for response forever.  I am thinking about changing my entire project to remove spring reactive framework and convert to sync non reactive regular spring framework which willl take weeks. Overall I had bad experience with reactive spring framework in large projects.

Comment: Cepr0 I fixed the problem by downgrading to spring boot 2.0 release instead of 2.1 release. Now your code works. I have read in blogs that using block in reactive spring application is anti-pattern. Is there a  solution without using BlockOptional or block() ?

Comment: Cepr0 unfortunately once again your solution does not work in my project because some controller actions also saves the user from values in the query parameters in the request. Since your updateUserStat runs in its own background thread saving the user, If your background thread saves user later it overwrites the value saved byy controller action. So I am still looking for a solution that makes sure the user is saved in webfilter before passing on to controller action.

Comment: @ace Could you please specify what exactly do you need? You need to perform two non-blocking operations, (1) find an existing user / or save new user, (2) create a page view and update the user, on the web filter before a controller? Or you need to do something with 'creating a page view and updating the user' which is a rather slow operation and which hangs a browser?

Comment: Cepr0 I want to create pageview, update save user in webfilter BEFORE  passing control to controller actions which also save user with its own different update. All this without hanging the browser or running wbfilter user save in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

For gathering page view stats I'll suggest to change the strategy and use Actuator and Micrometer instead:

1. Add the actuator dependency to your project
2. Expose the [relevant endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) (here, `metrics`)
3. Go to `/actuator/metrics` and select the metric for server HTTP requests (see the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metrics-web-flux)).

Micrometer offers way more and helps you to get your metrics right, like: taking into account GC pauses when measuring time, providing histograms/percentiles/..., and more.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant which creates pageview and updates the user in the webfilter in a non-blocking way, before passing a request to the controller:

```java
@Bean
public WebFilter filter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        ServerHttpRequest req = exchange.getRequest();
        String uri = req.getURI().toString();
        log.info("[i] Web Filter: received the request: {}", uri);

        var headers = req.getHeaders();
        List<String> tokenList = headers.get("token");

        if (tokenList != null && tokenList.get(0) != null) {
            String token = tokenList.get(0);
            Mono<User> foundUser = userRepo
                    .findByToken(token)
                    .doOnNext(user -> log.info("[i] Web Filter: {} has been found", user));
            return updateUserStat(foundUser, exchange, chain, uri);
        } else {
            String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            Mono<User> createdUser = userRepo
                    .save(new User(token))
                    .doOnNext(user -> log.info("[i] Web Filter: a new {} has been created", user));
            return updateUserStat(createdUser, exchange, chain, uri);
        }
    };
}
```

```java
private Mono<Void> updateUserStat(Mono<User> userMono, ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain, String uri) {
    return userMono
            .doOnNext(user -> exchange.getAttributes().put("_token", user.getToken()))
            .doOnNext(u -> {
                String token = exchange.getAttribute("_token");
                log.info("[i] Web Filter: token attribute has been set to '{}'", token);
            })
            .flatMap(user -> pageViewRepo.save(new PageView(uri)).flatMap(user::addPageView).flatMap(userRepo::save))
            .doOnNext(user -> {
                int numberOfPages = 0;
                List<PageView> pageViews = user.getPageViews();
                if (pageViews != null) {
                    numberOfPages = pageViews.size();
                }
                log.info("[i] Web Filter: {} has been updated. Number of pages: {}", user, numberOfPages);
            })
            .then(chain.filter(exchange));
}
```

This code produces the following results:

1) Token is not present: create a new user, create a page view, update the new user, pass a request to controller

```
2019-01-20 14:39:10.033 [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Web Filter: received the request: http://localhost:8080/users?test=784
2019-01-20 14:39:10.110 [ctor-http-nio-3] : Inserting Document containing fields: [token, _class] in collection: user
2019-01-20 14:39:10.206 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Web Filter: a new User(id=5c446bee24c86426ac6c0ae5, token=fba944cd-decb-4923-9757-724da5a60061) has been created
2019-01-20 14:39:10.212 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Web Filter: token attribute has been set to 'fba944cd-decb-4923-9757-724da5a60061'
2019-01-20 14:39:11.227 [     parallel-1] : Inserting Document containing fields: [URL, createdDate, _class] in collection: pageView
2019-01-20 14:39:11.242 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : Saving Document containing fields: [_id, token, pageViews, _class]
2019-01-20 14:39:11.256 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Web Filter: User(id=5c446bee24c86426ac6c0ae5, token=fba944cd-decb-4923-9757-724da5a60061) has been updated. Number of pages: 1
2019-01-20 14:39:11.289 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Controller: handling 'get all users' request. Token attribute is 'fba944cd-decb-4923-9757-724da5a60061'
2019-01-20 14:39:11.369 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class io.github.cepr0.demo.User in collection: user
```

2) Token is present: find an existing user, create a page view, update the user, pass a request to controller

```
2019-01-20 14:51:21.983 [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Web Filter: received the request: http://localhost:8080/users?test=538
2019-01-20 14:51:22.074 [ctor-http-nio-3] : Created query Query: { "token" : "b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
2019-01-20 14:51:22.092 [ctor-http-nio-3] : find using query: { "token" : "b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
2019-01-20 14:51:22.102 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Web Filter: User(id=5c434c2eb338ac3530cbd56d, token=b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd) has been found
2019-01-20 14:51:22.102 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Web Filter: token attribute has been set to 'b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd'
2019-01-20 14:51:23.103 [     parallel-2] : Inserting Document containing fields: [URL, createdDate, _class] in collection: pageView
2019-01-20 14:51:23.115 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : Saving Document containing fields: [_id, token, pageViews, _class]
2019-01-20 14:51:23.117 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Web Filter: User(id=5c434c2eb338ac3530cbd56d, token=b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd) has been updated. Number of pages: 13
2019-01-20 14:51:23.118 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Controller: handling 'get all users' request. Token attribute is 'b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd'
2019-01-20 14:51:23.119 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
```

3) Token is present but user is not found: pass a request to controller

```
2019-01-20 14:52:41.842 [ctor-http-nio-3] : [i] Web Filter: received the request: http://localhost:8080/users?test=513
2019-01-20 14:52:41.844 [ctor-http-nio-3] : Created query Query: { "token" : "-b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd" }, Fields: { }, Sort: { }
2019-01-20 14:52:41.845 [ctor-http-nio-3] : find using query: { "token" : "-b613b810-cc36-4961-ad2e-db44f52cd2dd" } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
2019-01-20 14:52:41.850 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : [i] Controller: handling 'get all users' request. Token attribute is 'null'
2019-01-20 14:52:41.850 [ntLoopGroup-2-2] : find using query: { } fields: Document{{}} for class: class User in collection: user
```

Demo: [sb-reactive-filter-demo(branch: update-user-in-web-filter)](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-reactive-filter-demo/tree/update-user-in-web-filter)

Comment: TL;DR : Instead of using `subscribe()` to invoke the save to mongoDB (which sends it to a parallel thread on which you have no control left), let the `flatMap` operator subscribe to the `save` which makes the outer chain wait until the save completes.

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani I use `flatMap`, not `subscribe`: `.flatMap(user -> pageViewRepo.save(new PageView(uri)).flatMap(user::addPageView).flatMap(userRepo::save))` What do you mean?..

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't correcting you. I was trying to explain the primary problem that you fixed, for people who were looking for a summary.