# How to return after successful return from subscribe within flatMap in spring reactor web app?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

Below code compiles fine:

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    ........

 .flatMap(user-> {
            userRepository.save(user).subscribe();
            return chain.filter(exchange);
  });

......
```

chain.filter(exchange) whose return type is Mono(Void) delegates to the next web filter in the chain.

But I need to invoke the line return chain.filter(exchange); after successful completion of userRepository.save  otherwise it fails to save the user when next webfilter runs.

I tried below code but it does not even compile.

```
.flatMap(user-> {
userRepository.save(user).subscribe(u -> chain.filter(exchange) );

});
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return
...
.flatMap(userRepository::save)
.then(chain.filter(exchange));
```

1) Combine calling filter and userRepository to one chain;

2) If `userRepository::save`caused error, data emits will be stopped and request  aborted, otherwise `then()` will call `chain.filter(exchange)`.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not work. thank you.

Comment: what does save method return? And could you provide full your code from filter?

Comment: it returns Mono<User>. I posted another question related to this that shows full source code.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651090/how-to-use-subscribe-within-map-context-in-spring-reactor-web-app

Comment: How do you define that User has not saved?

Comment: Problem occurs in downstream controller endpoints which also modify user and save but actually its not saved. Something could be wrong in other  controller code.